# Conditional rendering and image path in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, module, path

I don't really understand one moment. Let's say I have a component which conditionally renders data like this:

```
<div>
{isLoading ? <img src="../pathname/img.jpg" alt="loading" /> : <Page />}
</div>
```

Image is not rendered this way, shows a broken file icon. However, if I **import** the same image it works just fine:

```
import loadingImage from "../pathname/img.jpg"
<div>
{isLoading ? <img src={loadingImage} alt="loading" /> : <Page />}
</div>
```

I use `npm start` and my editor is VS Code. Do you know may be what is the reason to import it and not just simply provide a path name in `src` even if path is the same? The path I provided and file name was 100% correct in the first example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That happens because your image probably isn't inside `public` folder.

You can add assets to the public folder and then you will have access to it.

e.g. For the code below, you will need a `pathname` folder with the img.jpg inside the `public` folder.

`<img src="../pathname/img.jpg" alt="loading" />`

But the best way to do this is using import in JavaScript files.
This mechanism provides a number of benefits:

- Scripts and stylesheets get minified and bundled together to avoid
  extra network requests.
- Files are included in the bundle
- Missing files cause compilation errors instead of 404 errors for your
  users.
- Result filenames include content hashes so you don’t need to worry
  about browsers caching their old versions.

With `import`, when the page is rendered, you will see sometinhg like this in the image: `src="/static/media/img.xxxxx.jpg"`. Thats because using import tells webpack to include that file in the bundle.

You can check more here - [adding-images-fonts-and-files](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/) and here [using-the-public-folder](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/)

Comment: Indeed the image is not in public but in src folder. It's very helpful information Luis, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You miss the curly brackets. This will work:

```
<div>
  {isLoading ? <img src={'../pathname/img.jpg'} alt='loading' /> : <Page />}
</div>
```

Comment: I though the same at the beginning however it's not the case. Image is still displayed broken this way. Also I tried to change url to something like `./`, `/`, `.` and none of it worked. I believe Luis got the point here, the image I tried to render is not in public folder but in src.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't `import` the image file url then if you're using a webpack type bundler it won't include the file in the final build for you (to save you including unnecessary files that are not used).

The best way is to tell the bundler you need the file with an `import` statement. It will then store the file efficiently and auto update the URL reference as it gets updated in the final build.

You could also put the image in a public folder BUT this has several downsides as noted by other answers here.In one situation I was trying to update the URL string to use in CSS as a `background-image:` - but at run time, the file structure will have been changed by your web-bundler (but it won't understand it needs to update a string) so your URL reference will point to an incorrect location.

There's some good reading here:
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/react-background-image-tutorial-how-to-set-backgroundimage-with-inline-css-style/